# Create Java Random from the size of the List

Tags: java, list, random

I have created a method to randomize the list:

```
public <T> List<T> randomize(List<T> list) {
    LinkedList<T> randomizedList = new LinkedList<>();
    Random random = new Random(list.size());
    for (int i = random.nextInt(); i < list.size(); i++) {
        randomizedList.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return randomizedList;
}
```

The list that I am passing to this method contains for e.g. five elements. When I am creating `Random random = new Random(list.size());` I expect so when I call `random.nextInt()` what it will return me the random integer which will be an index of the list element.

But when I call `random.nextInt();` instead of returning the number from the interval `[0, 4]` (which I expect to be returned) it returns me the value of for e.g.: `-349120689`. Which gives me an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -349120689, Size: 5`.

Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: Any particular reason you do not want to use `Collections.shuffle(list)`?

Comment: I am just experimenting. I want to know why this doesn't work as I expect it to work.

Comment: Note the argument to Random's constructor is not upper bound but rather the seed.

Comment: @JimBolster - fair enough, in that case you need to pass `size` as an argument to your call to `random.nextInt()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `new Random(list.size());` this sets the seed of the Random number generator to `list.size();` I suggest changing to `new Random()` (which will give you a seed based on the current time of the system). Preferably though, you'd want to reuse the same Random object at all times.
2. `random.nextInt();` here is where you'd want to put `random.nextInt(list.size());` which will give you a number from 0 to list.size() - 1.
3. Even with the above changes, your code would just give you a sublist of the list starting at a random index and going until the end. Use `Collections.shuffle(list)` instead.

To do a real shuffling, you would need to "remember" which elements
    you have inserted or not. In pseudo-code, you could do the
    following:

- Copy the original list to a new one, let's call it "orig"
- Create a new, empty, list, let's call it "result"
- As long as the orig list has elements, get an element at random index and add it to the result list. Remove the chosen element from orig list.
- Return result list.

Answer (score 2):

> I expect so when I call random.nextInt() what it will return me the random integer which will be an index of the list element.

You've misunderstood the purpose of the `Random(long)` constructor. The purpose of that constructor is to specify a *seed* for the list. You *don't* want to do this - it would mean that every collection of size 5 is always shuffled the same way.

You specify the range on each call to `nextInt`. So if you want a random number between 0 (inclusive) and `max` (exclusive) you just use:

```
int value = random.nextInt(max);
```

However, it would be much better just to use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) instead of writing your own code to do this - assuming you really *want* a shuffle (which isn't what your current approach would give you anyway - even after fixing the `nextInt` call, you'd end up 
with basically a sublist, because `nextInt()` is only called once. So if the first call to `nextInt()` returns 2 (in a list of 5) you'd end up returning a new list containing the final 3 elements. I strongly suspect that's not what you were trying to do.

As a side-note, when you want to know why an API isn't behaving the way you expect it to, **read the documentation**. The documentation of the [`Random(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) constructor and [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) are pretty clearly *not* the behaviour you were expecting.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code would not give `independent random elements from the list` but rather a sublist starting at a random index. random.nextInt is only called once, to initialize `i`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public <T> List<T> randomize(List<T> list) {
    LinkedList<T> randomizedList = new LinkedList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = random.nextInt(list.size()); i < list.size(); i++) {
        randomizedList.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return randomizedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `Random` constructor is a random seed, not the maximum of what it returns.

Pass the maximum number to [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the argument to `nextInt(n)` (upper bound for the randomization) with the argument to the constructor (random seed). You shoudl use `nextInt(list.size)`, and probably, initialize the Random object using `new Random()`.